# how to run code directly for chrome and not IE i.e. how to create new object for chrome to run?

Tags: powershell

To run code in IE we do -

```
$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
```

But to run the code by default in chrome and not IE what can we do?

Thanks.

Comment: Try [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=powershell+google+chrome+automation&oq=powershell+google+chrome+automation). I don't think there is a PowerShell API for Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight forward answer is you can not. Because chrome does not have a COM interface like IE.

However, you can simply start chrome by.

```
Start-Process chrome "www.google.com"
```

But beware, you can only do that.. not much anything else. If automating is what you would want to do you may try something like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)